# How to draw a cone in Sage?

Tags: surfaces, sagemath

Given a cone with equation

z^2 = x^2 + y^2,

how would I draw it in Sage?

I tried turning it into a function and passing arguments but it didn't work out for me.

Comment: Try to give a look to the Sage's Reference Manual precisely here:http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/plot/plot3d/implicit_plot3d.html#sage.plot.plot3d.implicit_plot3d.implicit_plot3d

Comment: Thanks, I got this with implicit_plot :). If you wan't, answer it so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have drawn the cone with the following code:

```
var('x,y,z')
implicit_plot3d(x^2+y^2-z^2==0, (x, -3, 3), (y, -3,3), (z, -3,3))
```

Comment: Yeah, found it just a second ago. Thanks alot.